# AWK Identify duplicates from two columns but print the first instance

Tags: bash, awk

Newbie here, I need to remove the rows that contain duplicates in two columns (i.e. row1 and row2 has the same value in column 1, delete one of the rows and keep one and do the same for column one) Files are tab delimited

Here is example data

```
580615  580795  Del
580769  580795  Del
656123  657154  Del
656123  657195  Del
```

expected ouput

```
580769  580795  Del
656123  657154  Del
```

I am using Bash and this is a intermediary step in a pipeline I am developing.

I have tried to use this

```
awk 'seen[$1, $2]++ == 1' file
```

and

```
awk 'n=x[$1,$2]{print n"\n"$0;} {x[$1,$2]=$0;}' file
```

but I don't get any output.

Any suggestions will be appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: wrt `this is a intermediary step in a pipeline I am developing` - you'd almost certainly be better off just doing whatever it is all in one awk script than with a bunch of separate pipes and commands. You should [edit] your example to show what the expected output would be if you have a value in column1 of one row and column 2 of another row - right now idk if that would be considered duplicate rows or not. Including that in your example would be no effort at all on your part and make that requirement crystal clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk '!a[$1]++ && !b[$2]++' file

580615  580795  Del
656123  657154  Del
```

This keeps 2 associative arrays `a` and `b` with unique values of column 1 and column 2.

Comment: Hi Thanks alot it worded perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can do:

`awk '{ f[$1]+=1; s[$2]+=1; if(f[$1]==1 && s[$2]==1) print $0;}' file`

You capture every line and count the number of occurrences for each column (**f**irst and **s**econd). If the two columns are new then we print the line.

Answer (score 0):

`$ cat file`

```
580615  580795  Del
580769  580795  Del
656123  657154  Del
656123  657195  Del
```

1. using `sort`:

   ```
   $ sort -uk1,1 file | sort -uk2,2
   ```

`-k1,1` sorts the 1st row and deletes the duplicates, then

`-k2,2` sorts the 2nd row and removes duplicates

2. using `sort` and `uniq`:

   ```
   $ sort -uk1,1 file | uniq -f1
   ```

Ouput:

```
580615  580795  Del
656123  657154  Del
```

If add `-r` to `sort`

```
$ sort -uk1,1r file | sort -uk2,2
```

then ouput

```
580769  580795  Del
656123  657154  Del
```